# make elements expand to fill container, but wrap at min-width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

This may not be possible without Flexbox, but is worth a shout.

I would like to have elements inside a container to be elastic and take all the lateral space available but when the window resizes and they reach a min-width, they wrap into a second line.
this fiddle has two lines of investigation: inline-blocks and tables.

http://jsfiddle.net/48HMj/
relevant code here:

```
.container{
    width:100%;
    background-color: yellow;

}
.container2{
    width:100%;
    background-color: lightblue;
    display:table;

}
.block {
    border:1px solid;
    display:inline-block;
    min-width:100px;
    width:auto;
    height:50px;
}
.cell {
    border:1px solid;
    display:table-cell;
    min-width:100px;
    width:auto;
    height:50px;
}
```

Table-cells behave quite in that manner, but as table cells, they are not supposed to wrap...

Thanks

Comment: What controls the width of the .cell/.block elements? Are they all the same size?

Comment: they have a min-width but when the parent container is wide enough they would expand to equally fill the space (very much like table cells). When the parent container is shrunk, they would wrap into two lines (as opposed to hold the parent to a minimum size)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question right but I made a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/brewersomething/Rh62G/1/) for you to examine.

Essentially I forked the "Live Demo" fiddle from User3660695 added the `.flexible` class to all the divs and added a media query rule to the container:

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {

    .container { display: block }

}
```

Hopefully that is the behavior you were looking for. Cheers!

Comment: Can anyone explain why my answer was downvoted?  I am new user on Stackoverflow so it would helpful to learn something from a downvote instead of just being irritated. I thought my answer was quite helpful.

Comment: I think that's because author asked for a solution without flexboxes. I'll upvote you still, though, because it can be done without flexboxes using that media query rule, it helped me out so thanks! :)